# Correct way of creating a polymer dart web component library?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to build a web component library using dart and polymer but I'm unable to make data binding work inside my components.

I've made a test app and a library.
The test app define a simple main component :

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/MyLib/main_app.html">

<polymer-element name="my-launcher">
  <template>
    <style>

    </style>

 <my-main-app></my-main-app>

</template>
 <script type="application/dart" src="launcher.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

That component imports and uses my-main-app defined in my library:

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_item.html">

<polymer-element name="my-main-app" >
  <template>
    <style>

    </style>
   <core-scaffold id="mainScaffold">
    <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
      <core-toolbar>MYAPP</core-toolbar>

      <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" selectedItem="{{mainMenuItem}}" selected="0">
        <core-item icon="settings" label="Activities"></core-item>
        <core-item icon="settings" label="Other"></core-item>
      </core-menu>

    </core-header-panel>
    <div tool>Activities</div> 
    <div>Hello we got some action here: 
      <br>
      <br>
      <paper-button label="Toggle Drawer" on-click="{{toggleDrawer}}" raisedButton>    </paper-button>
      <br>

      <template if="{{toggled==0}}">
        Panel is shown (int) ?
       </template>
       <template if="{{toggled==1}}">
        Panel is hidden (int) ?
       </template>
    </div>
</core-scaffold>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Everything works (paper components, panel drawer toggling when clicking on button) but the conditional template that doesn't react. The only work-around is to directly use Observable mixin and call "deliverChanges" in my method.

All the example I've found do not need to do this, even the paper components I'm using and that works in my test app work without the need to use the Observable mixin. So I'm wondering : What I'm  doing wrong ? What is the "right" way of creating a polymer dart component library ?

For completeness here is the code of the main app component (the worked around version using Observable mixin) :

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_item.dart';

@CustomTag('my-main-app')
class MyMainApp extends PolymerElement with Observable /* <- THIS SHOUDN'T BE NECESSARY! */ {

  @observable CoreItem mainMenuItem;

  @observable int toggled=0;

  CoreScaffold scaffold;

  MyMainApp.created() : super.created() {
  }

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    scaffold = $['mainScaffold'];  


  }

  void toggleDrawer() {
    toggled = 1 - toggled;
    scaffold.togglePanel();
    // THIS SHOULD NOT BE NECESSARY!!!!!
    deliverChanges();
  }
}
```

@edit : adding "index.html" sources for completeness:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TestAPp</title>

    <!-- include the web_components polyfills with support for Dart. -->
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Poylmer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

    <!-- import the click-counter -->
    <link rel="import" href="launcher.html">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testapp.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-launcher></my-launcher>
    <!-- bootstrap polymer -->
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using latest Polymer version (0.13.x), compiled to JS. 
@edit : fixed a typo.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. I would simplify your `toggled` and make it a `@observable bool showPanel = true;` and `void toggleDrawer() => showPanel != showPanel;`, `<template if="{{showPanel}}">`. Would be interesting if this works without the 'Observable hack'

Comment: Have you tried `deliverChanges();` without ` with Observable`? What Polymer version are you using? How does your `index.html` look like? Do you get any warnings when you launch the page?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer my first version was using a "bool" but I switched to an int to check if the problem was the datatype. It wasn't that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've tried calling deliverChanges() without using the mixin and it doesn't work. This think is drawing me mad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the reason it was not working. Not only in the main app but also  in the library pubspec there must be a transformer for polymer.

Here is the correct pubspec for my lib:

```
name: mylib
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  core_elements: '>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
  paper_elements: '>=0.1.0 <0.2.0'
  polymer: '>=0.13.0 <0.14.0'

transformers:
- polymer
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo.  First non-comment line in `main_app.html`: `<lik rel...` should be `<link rel...`.

Comment: I've edited the post. It was a bad copy&paste from my editor, the actual code I was running was correct. But thanks.

Comment: Would you mind posting your `launcher.dart`, `pubspec.yaml`, and `pubspec.lock` files? It's working for me, using core_elements "0.2.0+1", paper_elements "0.1.1+2", and polymer "0.13.1".  I created an "empty" launcher.dart (that is, a MyLauncher class extending PolymerElement and just declaring the `.created()` constructor), and everything works fine.

Comment: This is strange. Yesterday I was at home and, after renaming some files, suddenly it worked without the mixin hack. I was unable to reproduce the bad behaviour. But now I'm at office and again it is not working. I'm starting to hate Dart.

Comment: Same computer at home and office? Or different ones? If different, same Dart version in both?  Tried a fresh clone of the repo? (I'm assuming the code is in a git repo.)  Tried deleting the `build` folder and re-building?

Comment: Same computer. But the actual reason was the one in my answer. I've made several esperiments with or without the transformer but probably one must "kill" and restart a pub serve to properly rebuild everything so this is what happened : I added the transformer but and it was still not working. I went home and then it worked (because pub serve restarted) but I didn't recall I made that change. I reverted with no transformer and still was working. I returned in office and then it was not working anymore (pub server restarted).